Send audio file to koboldcpp with node.js
Recently, I have coded a node.js program that receive audio file and send to koboldcpp. But, when the koboldcpp receive the file, it return error:
"Whisper Transcribe Generating...error: failed to open WAV file from stdin
Whisper: Failed to read input wav data!"
I am sure the file is consist, at least I can play it in in winamp.
var upload_wave_to_kobolcpp=function(){
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {        
        try {
            const audioFilePath = './public/audio.wav';
            var audioBuffer=fs.createReadStream('./public/audio.wav');
            const {size} = fs.statSync('./public/audio.wav');           
            dd.d('audio read success');
            const response = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5001/v1/audio/transcriptions", 
                {audioBuffer}, 
                {
                    headers: {
                        //'Content-Type': 'audio/wav',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                        //'Content-Length': size,
                    },
            });
            dd.d('audio send success');
            console.log(response.data);
            resolve();
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
          }
    });
}


...I have found the answer by checking network request in the browser while I make a request in origin koboldcpp web UI. The link is http://domain:5000/api/extra/transcribe, not http://domain:5000/v1/audio/transcriptions, which is copied from koboldcpp API document, at the v1 area. And I just need to read the file and convert it into base64encode, then send it in json format, it work great.
